# Outlier in pearsons residuals after removing influential observations - How to remove?

Tags: r, logistic, residuals, cooks-distance

[image: Residuals for GLM]

I'm trying to run a GLM with multiple continuous preditor variables in R, cook's distance shows influential observations, I remove these and check my residuals for the model and have the outlier shown above.

When I run cooks distance again it shows no influential observations. I removed influential observations 4 over sample size.

How can I identify and remove the issue?

[image: Cooks distance before] [image: Cooks distance after]

Comment: What is the "issue" to which you refer??

Comment: Would the point sitting so far down on the y axis not cause problems for my model? I'm under the impression that for model validation my residuals have to be more consistant along the x axis around zero than this?

Comment: It depends on the model, on how much the inclusion of that point affects the results, on which results you are using, on the amount of data, and on the reliability of that datum.  But these are just basic generalities about assessing outlying data in any analytical setting.  Is there a *specific* question you are trying to ask?

Comment: what kind of GLM is that? The Pearson res plot looks weird.